# sort: write failed | broken pipe

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sort, head

Good evening,

The following is a piece of the code I'm using in a script. Launching from a SSH sesssion works fine, however, when it runs via cron, it displays broken pipe errors on screen.

I can't reproduce it via SSH.

Code:

```
IP=$(sort --random-sort /root/ips.csv | head -n 1); nc -zv -w 2 $IP 443 2>&1 | grep succeeded >> outfile
```

Error in screen:

```
sort: write failed: standard output; Broken pipe
sort: write error
```

Any tips/pointers?

Thank you!

Comment: Chances are that `cron`'s current working directory is not the location of `ips.csv`, so the file is not there to read, breaking the pipe.  Try `IP=$(sort --random-sort /path/to/ips.csv [...]`.

Comment: Good point. Actually I have the full path to the file, but I forgot to include it when editing the code to post online.

Comment: Since I can't seem to figure out how to make this code work, are there any alternatives to this code?

Objective is to randomize a list and connect to the first IP (occurance) of that list?

Answer (score 13):

When `head` finishes after handling the first line, it exits, closing the other end of the pipe. `sort` may still be trying to write more, and writing to a closed pipe or socket returns the EPIPE error. But it also raises the SIGPIPE signal, killing the process, unless the signal is ignored or handled. With the signal ignored, `sort` sees the error, complains, and exits. If the signal is not ignored, `sort` just dies.

We can use the [`trap` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap) to ignore a signal from the shell, getting the error:

```
$ trap "" PIPE
$ sort bigfile | head -1 > /dev/null 
sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
sort: write error
```

But sadly, we **can't** use `trap` to un-ignore the signal and get the desired behaviour, as [POSIX requires](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) that it's not allowed to do that in non-interactive shells (scripts). It does allow it for interactive shells, but Bash's `trap` doesn't do it in that case either.

To test:

```
sh$ trap '' PIPE                     # ignore the signal    
sh$ PS1='another$ ' bash             # run another shell
another$ trap - PIPE                 # try to reset the signal
                                     # it doesn't work
another$ sort bigfile |head -1 > /dev/null
sort: write failed: 'standard output': Broken pipe
sort: write error
```

Instead, we could use an external tool, like a Perl one-liner to run a script or command with the signal un-ignored (`sort` exits silently here):

```
another$ perl -e '$SIG{PIPE}="DEFAULT"; exec "@ARGV"' \
         'sort bigfile |head -1' > /dev/null 
another$
```

---

As for your situation with cron, the reason could be that systemd [apparently makes SIGPIPE ignored by default](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-August/021982.html), mentioning:

> [SIGPIPE is]
>   not really useful for normal daemons though, and as we try to provide a
>   good, useful execution environment for daemons, we turn this off. Of
>   course, shells and suchlike should turn this on again.

Of course, this is also mentioned [in the documentation (systemd.exec)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> `IgnoreSIGPIPE=`
>   Takes a boolean argument. If true, causes SIGPIPE to be ignored in the executed process. Defaults to true because SIGPIPE generally is useful only in shell pipelines.

On my Debian system, `/lib/systemd/system/cron.service` [explicitly sets `IgnoreSIGPIPE=false`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756047), undoing the systemd default for cron. You may want to check if that would help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Since `--random-sort` is a GNU extension anyway, you might as well use GNU `shuf` which comes from the same collection of GNU utilties (GNU `coreutils`):

```
ip=$(shuf -n 1 ips.tsv)
```

Beside avoiding the SIGPIPE issue, that is also more efficient as it doesn't need to shuffle the whole file as GNU `sort --random-sort` does (`shuf` uses some [*Reservoir Sampling* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) on large inputs to do that).

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution you could use this kind of Bash function to run pipe without broken pipe error and without hiding other possible error messages:

```
entire_pipe() {
    ( set -m; (
        trap 'exit 0' INT
        echo $BASHPID
        $1
    ) & wait $! ) |
    (
        trap 'trap - EXIT; kill -s INT -- -$pid 2>/dev/null || :' EXIT
        read -r pid
        $2
    )
}
```

To make this more portable, you could replace `$BASHPID` by `$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')`.

To use the function in case of this question you would replace

```
sort --random-sort /root/ips.csv | head -n 1
```

by

```
entire_pipe 'sort --random-sort /root/ips.csv' 'head -n 1'
```

This is supposed to work even if the left side of pipe starts descendant processes; they will be all interrupted.